# Converting arrow function to React.Component with children

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am making a blog in Gatsby.js and i have a problem converting this

```
const TemplateWrapper = ({children}) => (
<div>
  <Helmet
    title="My website"
    meta={[
      { name: 'description', content: 'A brief history of myself' },
      { name: 'keywords', content: 'myself, cv' },
    ]}
  />
  <Header />
  <div>
    {children()}
  </div>
  <Footer/>
</div>)
```

To a normal function. I tried creating React.Component class but it seems not to get the children. I aim to make a loading screen bar and thats why i want to convert it. I tried this

```
class Wrapper extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true
    };
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    setTimeout(() => this.setState({ loading: false }), 2500); 
  }
  render(){
    const { loading } = this.state;
    if(loading){
      return <Loader/>
    }
    return(
      <TemplateWrapper/>
    );
  }
}
```

And then i exported the Wrapper.. but it doesnt seem to work, it says children is not a function and it stucks on loading icon (Loader). Any ways to solve this?

Note. When i export default TemplateWrapper everything works perfectly!

Comment: Like the error says, `{children()}` this line seems weird. In this case you shouldn't need to call children as a function. Try replacing it with `{children}`

Comment: Ok but i don't see the children, only the parent component

Comment: Children will have to be defined in the `<Wrapper>` class.  So if we change its render method to contain `<TemplateWrapper>Testing Children!</TemplateWrapper>` we'll be able to see the `Testing Children!` text rendered out.